# Apache URL to File

Tags: apache, url

I'm looking for the configuration of Apache to read the URL and point it to a specific file.

For example:

`https:// api.example.com/file/key/info/moreinfo/etc.`

My intention is that this link will open file.php and that i can read the rest of the URL using PHP.

What configuration do i need in Apache to make this work?
I have multiple sub-domains but i only need it on 1 of my sub-domains.

Currently i'm testing with Synology WebStation >> Apache 2.4 & php 7.3.

Is this even possible with WebStation?
And how to edit the config file (I prefer a GUI, commandline only if needed).

Answer (score 0):

The directive FallBackResource was added to make this kind of configuration simple. Your script will receive the remainder of the URL in environment variables.